# Append future dates in dataframe with historical averages in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **daily** data frame (YYYY-MM-DD) of below form. Every Date has 2 types in the Type column, namely "A" and "B".

```
     Date         Type    Value
  2010-01-01       A         8
  2010-01-01       B         5
  2010-01-02       A         81
  2010-01-02       B         7

      ......
  2020-06-23       A         7
  2020-06-23       B         7.1
  2020-06-24       A         8
  2020-06-24       B         11
   ...........
  2021-10-09       A         5 
  2021-10-09       B         17
  2021-10-10       A         1
  2021-10-10       B         10
```

I want to append future dates to this data frame until the last date of current month such that Value for future date is equal to **past 10 year average for that particular date and type**.

For eg:  for date **2021-10-11**; Type A = Average of Values for *11 Oct from 2011 to 2020* of type A and so on.
I want to fill these future values until last day of current month.

```
     Date         Type    Value
  2021-10-11       A         Avg for 11 Oct from 2011 to 2020
  2021-10-11       B         Avg for 11 Oct from 2011 to 2020
  ..........
  2021-10-31       A         Avg for 31 Oct from 2011 to 2020
  2021-10-31       B         Avg for 31 Oct from 2011 to 2020
```

How can I achieve this in pandas.

I have tried below after filtering df for last 10 years data only:

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day, "Type"]).mean()
```

But how to plug back the values to the dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @vvv Can you please feedback about my answer ? Did it work or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this complex code snippet will work. I don't know if there is a simple way.

```
df.index = df.Date
df["new"] = df.Date.astype(str).str[-5:]
df=df.groupby(["new","Type"],sort=False).expanding().mean().reset_index().sort_values(["Date","Type"]).reset_index(drop=True)
df["Value"] = df.groupby(["new","Type"]).shift().Value
df=df[["Date","Type","Value"]]
```